# Can the OneNote API copy a notebook or section from one user to another user in Office 365

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I'm trying to copy section of a notebook, or even notebook itself, from a notebook in one user's OneDrive to another user's notebook in their OneDrive. The user I'm logged in as has permissions to read and write both notebooks. I'm getting the error response:

```
message=The specified resource ID does not exist.
@api.url=http://aka.ms/onenote-errors#C20102
code=20102
```

Where the path I'm using is of the form https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/users/{id}/notes/sections/{id}/copyToNotebook where the ids in that are for the source section.

which is presumably because the id in the post request represents a notebook under a different user.

If I was copying to a SharePoint site or group then the post request can have additional ids to identify that, so it be logical if there was a argument to identify the user to copy to.

Copying works perfectly when both notebooks are within the same user's OneDrive.

Is there any way of doing it between users in Office 365 OneDrive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can copy a section from one notebook to another user's notebook, as long as you have write permission to that user's notebook (or a notebook under another site).

In you scenario, the destination/post body has to contain the ID to the notebook, as well as the **siteCollectionId** and **siteId**, or the **groupId** of the site where the notebook is stored. (Checkout the message body format [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-copy#construct-the-message-body)). If you want to copy the section to another user's notebook, you will need the siteCollectionId and siteId of that user's OneDrive for Business; if you want to copy it to a notebook stored in a site, you will need the IDs for that site.

The reason you need those extra IDs is because by default the copy API will consider the destination notebook is stored in your OneDrive for Business. By specifying those IDs you tell the API that the destination is in another location. I'm assuming you didn't provide those IDs that you got the error.

You get get more information about obtaining the siteCollectionId and siteId [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-copy#request-and-response-information).

Comment: That's it exactly thanks. Needed the siteCollectionId and siteId of the personal OneDrive. Was expecting some sort of user id in there, but it is just based on a SharePoint site collection so that makes sense.

Comment: @qwerty this is exactly what I needed and a huge help!.  Like Richard, I was thinking the personal site was a OneDrive for business.  It is a individual SharePoint site that I can reference using ```myOrganization/siteCollections/{id}/sites/{id}```  If only Microsoft could add this comment/information to their dev documentation.